# Web mobile reliable height

Tags: javascript, android, ios, dom, height

Does anybody knows how can I get the exact client height on a **mobile device** using JavaScript?
I need to have the visible height (all page height except the keyboard (if displayed) and the address bar (if visible)).
I tried with window.innerHieght and document.documentElement.clientHeight but the returned values are not always reliable.
On iOS and Android, **randomically** when loading the page and showing/hideing the keyboard, the height is the height without the keyboard even if the keyboard is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can get answer from here: [How to calculate height of viewable area (i.e., window height minus address & bookmark bars) in mobile Safari for web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039628/how-to-calculate-height-of-viewable-area-i-e-window-height-minus-address-bo)

For example on ios7 safari:

- **window.innerHieght** is 529px which is the viewport height
- **screen.availHeight** is 548px which is the window.innerHeight plus address height
- **screen.height** is 568px which is the screen.availHeight plus status bar