# How to calculate height of viewable area (i.e., window height minus address & bookmark bars) in mobile Safari for web app?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, mobile-safari, ios7

What is the right way to calculate how much viewable space is available on mobile Safari? By viewing area, we mean the amount of the screen actually available to a web app, that is the window height minus the address and bookmark bars.

iOS 7 prevents hiding of the address bar, and we need to properly account for the viewport height.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` will give the width and height of the viewport.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work on iOS 7; window.innerHeight doesn't yield the height after subtracting for the address and bookmark bars. do we need to do something else?

Comment: On my iPhone 4S running iOS 7.0.2, `window.screen.availHeight` gives 460. That is 480px minus the height of the status bar. With both the address bar and tab bar visible, `window.innerHeight` is 373. If I then scroll to minimise the address bar and hide the tab bar, `window.innerHeight` reports 441.

Comment: Hmm, what value do you get when you visit this page: http://www.tekiki.com/default/test? We get 1109. The code for the entire page is this: <script type='text/javascript'>


 setTimeout( function() {
  alert( window.innerHeight ); 
 }, 500 );
 
</script>

Comment: Add this to the head element: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"> and you'll get 372.

Comment: `window.screen.availHeight` returns 548 on iphone5S/ios7.0.3 with or without the toolbar and big/small adress bar ; `window.innerHeight` returns 529 initialy and 460 after scrolling.

Comment: This does not work, because the `Layout` event on the mobile safari fires with the initial dimension that is different from the logical pixels. If the script runs before the style computation, this `innerHeight/Width` would be wrong.
currently there is no event hook to trigger on, and a simple setTimeout is the only solution available as far as I know.

Comment: Timeout still gives me the wrong value for innerHeight

Comment: @MarcelFalliere 2020, you should write it as an independent answer, because it's the only one works

Answer (score 9):

For anyone who comes in 2020, `window.screen.availHeight` is the only one that works as `@Marcel Falliere`'s comment below.

Answer (score 4):

Set the CSS `height` of your root container element (let's call it `rootElement`) to the height of the view port:

```css
.root-element {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Then, when the page renders, run this code to update `rootElement` height to the viewport height minus the size of the browser UI bars (for example, on iOS Safari: top address bar, bottom navigation bar…):

```js
const rootElement = document.querySelector(".root-element")
const viewPortH = rootElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
const windowH = window.innerHeight;
const browserUiBarsH = viewPortH - windowH;
rootElement.style.height = `calc(100vh - ${browserUiBarsH}px)`;
```

This solution sets the size of your root container to what is available, but it also keep the possibility for the browser to adapt `rootElement` height when the window is resized (when used on a desktop, for instance).

Comment: **Works on Android Chrome, version-87.0428066 too, Tested.**  
*Tip: use the value as a css variable*

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 5 years old post, but this problem still persists as i can tell. My workaround:
Use a HTML Element on the page  which is styled with CSS: `.el{ height:100vh; }` and retrieve the height in pixel to Javascript by using jQuery: `$('.el').height();`

If you don't have a practical use for such a element you might create one on the fly for the sole purpose of masuring the viewport:

```
var vh = $('<div style="height:100vh"></div>"').appendTo('body').height();
$('body div:last-child').remove();
```